# What is the purpose of set clock skew in wcf security mode settings

Tags: c#, wcf

I have got an issue caused by clock skew in my WCF application. I'm confused why Microsoft set this rule. Why did the service refused the request when clock skew between server and client was over the max value been set. (I not sure if it was refused by server, it raised exception any way).

What is the purpose of set clock skew in wcf security mode settings ?

Answer (score 3):

This is a security feature to guard against [replay attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack). 
Essentially the security timestamp when the message was created is only valid for a limited time and expires after that. But for this to work the service and the client have to agree on a common time within a tolerance. This is what the maxclockskew setting does.

Some information here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733063.aspx

Comment: Hi Pratik, thanks for your post, I've read the article you referred, I did not get how tolerance avoid replay attacks, why adversaries don't change the time in the message he/her intercepted.
PS: I think session tokens is better , who knows what the clock on client machine will be.

Comment: The messages are signed after timestamping. see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022053/how-does-timestamp-helps-in-preventing-replay-attacks-in-webservices